# How can I read the descriptor for the "Characteristic User Description"?

Tags: bluetooth, file-descriptors, bluez

I am trying to get my Linux machine to communicate with several micro-controllers that have BLE chips. I am attempting to do this using the attributes that already come with the micro-controllers. The micro-controllers being used are bluno nanos. The issue I am having is that I do not know how the vendor specific attributes work and I do not know how to access information on how they do work. This is what I have so far.

```
#bluetoothctl
#connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
#list-attributes
Primary Service
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D0_39_72_A0_51_82/service0023
0000dfb0-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Unknown
Characteristic
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D0_39_72_A0_51_82/service0023/char0027
0000dfb2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Unknown
Descriptor
/org/bluez/hci0/dev_D0_39_72_A0_51_82/service0023/char0027/desc0029
00002901-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Characteristic User Description
```

And it continues to list more attributes but those are unimportant to this question. So, my question is, How do I access the descriptor so I can read the "Characteristic User Description"? Or, what is this descriptor for? Am I misunderstanding its purpose? Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any one who is doing ble stuff with the bluno nanos this is what I found.

```
public static final String SerialPortUUID="0000dfb1-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
public static final String CommandUUID="0000dfb2-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb";
```

That is part of the source code for all current bluno nanos. This is what I was trying to figure out by this question.